# Space complexity comparison between recursion and dynamic programming, which is better?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

I've seen that the space complexity of recursion depends on space used in call stack. And dynamic programming uses extra space to improve time complexity. So does recursion is better than dynamic programming in terms of space complexity?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the depth of recursion

Answer (score 0):

Not if the dynamical programming is done optimally. It just makes explicit the storage requirements which are used anyway by recursive algorithm implicitly on the stack. It doesn't add any extra space needlessly (unless it's implemented suboptimally).

Consider Fibonacci calculation. The recurrence formula seem to only require two values, `Fib(n+2) = Fib(n+1) + Fib(n)`, but due to recursion the calculation will actually use *O(n)* space on the stack anyway. Due to the double recursion the time though will be exponential, whereas with the dynamic programming filling the same space from the ground up both space and time will be linear.

Comment: Not so fast.  In most problems that we want to use dynamic programming in, its space requirements are greater than the naive recursive solution.

Comment: this just can't be true if we implement it through memoization, right? we just reify the control stack as the results table. I ignore the constant factors of course and include the stack in total space used.

Comment: Consider subset-sum of positive integers.  The naive recursive solution, implemented in the easiest way, has memory requirements `O(n)`.  (`n` levels in the call stack, each of which gets a single number and returns a subset.) Its run-time is `O(2^n)`.  Turn it into dynamic programming with top-down memoization and the run-time and memory space is now `O(n * S)` where `S` is the desired sum.  Write bottom up DP and run-time remains the same but the memory requirement drops to `O(S)`.  (Because you get to free memory.)

Comment: This is the usual set of tradeoffs, but there is one more.  Writing bottom up is fundamentally harder than writing top-down, and for a complex problem you may be unable to figure out the bottom-up approach.  So I recommend starting with memoization first, and worrying about bottom-up only if there seems to be a reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you pick your favorite problem that dynamic programming is appropriate for, such as subset-sum, there are generally three approaches.

1. Recursion
2. Bottom up dynamic programming.
3. Top down dynamic programming, aka recursion with memoization.

In terms of time complexity, recursion is usually worse by an exponential factor, and the other two are equivalent.  (That is why we do dynamic programming.)

In terms of space requirements, recursion is usually the best (just have to track the current attempt at a solution), and often (though not always) bottom up is better than top-down by a factor of `n` (the size of your problem).  That is because you know when you're done with a particular piece of data and can throw it away.

In terms of ease of writing the code, recursion is usually easiest, followed by top-down, followed by bottom-up.  (Though the memory savings of bottom up make it worthwhile to learn.)

Now you may ask, are there other tradeoffs possible between memory and performance?  It isn't done very often, but there is. Do top down and use an LRU cache (when the cache gets too big you discard the least recently used value from it).  You will get a different tradeoff, though figuring out what the tradeoff is is kind of complicated.